# HTML5 Boilerplate - Mobile Safari Background Issue

Tags: css, background, mobile-safari, html5boilerplate

I am in no way pretending to be a developer, but I do try and code sites I design from time to time.

I am running into an issue where I used HTML5 Boilerplate to code a site and when on a desktop browser, it looks fine (http://cl.ly/image/3j0L3Q3k3W1S), but as soon as I move to Mobile Safari, the background seems to get nudged around quite a bit (http://cl.ly/image/0q0I2q1f1Y1c).

I've had the same problem with another site, so I'm assuming it's something in the code that I don't know about...

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!